# UnitOfWork + Repository patterns and Entity Framework impersonation

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, repository-pattern, impersonation, unit-of-work

I have used UnitOfWork and Repository patterns in my application with EF.

Actually my design provides that the UnitOfWork would create the ObjectContext class and inject inside the Repository concrete class. For example:

**UnitOfWork.cs (initialization)**

```
public DefaultUnitOfWork() {
    if (_context == null) {
        _context = new MyDataContext(ConfigSingleton.GetInstance().ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

**UnitOfWork.cs (getting a repository instance)**

```
public CustomerRepository Customers {
    get {
        if (_customers == null) {
            _customers = new CustomerRepository(_context);
        }
        return _customers;
    }
}
```

This way the Repository classes have an already defined ObjectContext class and they can use it's methods to retrieve and update data.
This works nice.

Now I need to execute my queries impersonating the Application Pool Identity so I have decided to wrap the code in the constructor of the UnitOfWork within the impersonation.

Unfortunately this does not work because the `ObjectContext` is then passed to the Repository constructor and used later when a client of the repository calls, for example, `FindAll()`.

I have experienced that the real connection to the database is made right before doing the query by Entity Framework and not exactly when I am creating the `ObjectContext` itself.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use one or more ObjectContext Factories (to create ObjectContexts), using different creation criteria, such as Connection String, for example.  Your UnitOfWork could leverage a factory to get its Context and so could the Repository, but I think you've missed the point of UnitOfWork if it is leveraging a different ObjectContext than your Repository.

A UnitOfWork should consist of one or more operations that should be completed together, which could easily leverage multiple repositories.  If the repositories have their own ObjectContexts separate from the UnitOfWork, I don't see how committing the UnitOfWork will achieve it's purpose.

I think either I've misinterpreted your question completely or you've left out some pertinent details.  Good Luck!